# Can we define a subspace as a linear combination of vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

Sorry for the dumb question, but I'm new into Linear Algebra and I'm still trying to figure out things.

In the vector space $\mathbb{R^4}$, the subspace $W$ is generated from the vectors $w_1=\left[ \begin{matrix} 1 & 1 & -1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right], w_2=\left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \end{matrix} \right], w_3=\left[ \begin{matrix} 1 & 1 & -1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right]$.

Is this the same as defining the subspace $W $ as the linear combination of these vectors $W=L[w_1, w_2, w_3]$?

Comment: A subspace is a *set* of *all* linear combinations of a collection of vectors (not just a single linear combination).  I know that it doesn't feel like much, but the language is quite important here.

Comment: I got it. Thanks! :)